# How do I grant access to an Amazon Redshift user to read the system tables, views, logs, etc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a user in Amazon Redshift. I want that user to be able to do read-only queries against the system tables:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_system-tables.html

But I don't know how to grant a user who is not a superuser access to these tables as it does not appear to be documented anywhere on amazon.

Comment: Is making the user a superuser an option?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously you don't want to grant superuser to another user just so they can see system logs. Being able to monitor is a very common use case that shouldn't require giving someone *carte blanche* access.

Thankfully you have the ability to grant access to system tables using the `syslog access` option.

```
alter user user123 syslog access unrestricted
```

See the Redshift documentation for additional details:

- [System Tables and Views Reference - Visibility of data in system tables and views](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_system-tables.html#c_visibility-of-data)
- [ALTER USER - SYSLOG Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_USER.html#alter-user-syslog-access)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Superuser, you can make other user as superuser or create a new superuser and then other user can query system table and views. Use createuser privilege. 
Below is the sample query

```
create user user_super createuser password '1234';
alter user user_super createuser;
```

Be careful while making any superuser, superuser gets all access including grant and revoke and query run from superuser always goes to query-1 and will make other queries wait until finished.