# How to grant permission to system tables and view in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to grant permission to particular user for system tables,system logging and system view.

Answer (score 2):

I've read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305905/3628435) that granting syslog access would help, but that did not work for me on view  `svv_table_info`.
what did work for me was simple grant select, but only when I've added the system schema name too.

```
grant select on pg_catalog.svv_table_info to user;
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Elle said is correct, but there are some system tables that require you to run additional queries to give a non-super user visibility to rows in certain tables (such as STL_QUERY and STL_QUERY_TEXT). See [Visibility of data in system tables and views](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_visibility-of-data.html) for details.

Run `ALTER USER <your_user> WITH SYSLOG ACCESS UNRESTRICTED;` then run `GRANT SELECT on pg_catalog.<table_name> to <your_user>;`

**NOTE** Giving a user unrestricted access to system tables gives that user visibility to data which might contain sensitive user-generated data.